# How to create new columns based on values from another column dynamically

Tags: sql-server

I would like to create new columns based on values from another column dynamically.

For example ( fruits and quantity may be changed from time to time so the code should be able to create new columns as needed):
I can do a case statement to create the two new columns : Banana, Apple.But how can I do it dynamically? - i.e tomorrow I'll get a new fruit like "Melon" or one fruit will be omitted.

```
ID FRUIT QUANTITY
22 Banana 5
33 Banana 1
44 Apple  3
```

Output

```
ID FRUIT QUANTITY Banana Apple
22 Banana 5         1      0
33 Banana 1         1      0
44 Apple  3         0      1
```

Comment: You're wanting to transform rows into columns which can be done via [pivot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx). However, because you want to dynamically create columns, you would have to go one step further and build a [Dynamic SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) statement. This is because Pivot expects you to define the columns (i.e. it's static), it won't dynamically create them from your `FRUIT` data. Generally speaking, it's easier and more practical to perform pivoting in whatever tool you use to present (i.e. display) the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following dynamic SQL pivot query

```
--create table FruitQty (ID int, FRUIT varchar(25), QUANTITY int)
--insert into FruitQty select 1,'Melon',5
--insert into FruitQty select 2,'Apple',3
--insert into FruitQty select 3,'Apple',5

DECLARE @Fruits nvarchar(max)
SELECT @Fruits =
 STUFF(
 (
  select distinct ',[' + Fruit + ']'
  from FruitQty
  for xml path('')
 ),
 1,1,'')

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
SELECT @SQL = N'
select
 *
from (
 select
  FRUIT,
  QUANTITY
 from FruitQty
 ) Data
PIVOT (
 SUM(QUANTITY)
 FOR FRUIT
 IN (
  ' + @Fruits + '
 )
) PivotTable
'
exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

You can find details and samples on [dynamic SQL pivot query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-dynamic-pivot-table-example-code.aspx) at referenced SQL Server tutorial

I hope it helps